# Proportional Editing - Vertices moving for no reason

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have an arm mesh. When I try to rotate some vertices with proportional editing some vertices move with it for no reason.

[image]

This doesn't happen with all vertices.

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34615)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have turned on 'X Mirror' for edit mode. This is a a tool which will mirror changes in edit mode across the object's local X axis.

In edit mode you can turn this off by going to the 'Options' tab in the 3D view toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) and turning off 'X Mirror'.

[image]