# Mirror-Modifier applied, but still mirroring

Tags: mirror, sculpting

I made my first sculpt model and I used a mirror modifier. But then I applied the mirror modifier, because I got a strange edge on the mirror line in sculpt mode.
Now I modeled it, but it still mirrors the model, what in the beginning was good, but sometime I want to do asymmetrical things.

What did I wrong?
Many thanks for your help!!
Happy modeling :D

[image: model + modifiers]

Comment: Does the answer on this question help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26165/proportional-editing-vertices-moving-for-no-reason/26167#26167

Comment: Does it mirror when you sculpt only? Maybe you need to disable the symmetry in tools tab?

Comment: Thanks, but I looked in the options menu there and the X mirror option wasn't checked, but the model still mirroring :/
Is this a bug? I would prefer, that I have done something wrong :/

Comment: @Highstaker You could add that as an answer to take this off the unanswered list.

Comment: Never mind... for some reason my browser didn't show Vince's answer.

Comment: @pgmath I wasn't sure if it was the case or not, and didn't want to get downvotes if I were wrong

Comment: @Highstaker  I just meant once the problem is established it's usually good to put the solution as an answer.  As an aside, a downvote should be just for a blatantly wrong or very poor answer, in a case like this it was a pretty likely solution so I personally probably would have posted it as an answer.  But that's just personal preference, some people like to clear it up in comments first.

Comment: @PGmath maybe I should be less humble then XD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to disable symmetry lock. It only happens in sculpt mode, the option to turn it off or on can be found under tools  >  symmetry lock.

Click the shaded option to disable, x by default.

[image]

Don't worry, you did nothing wrong