# When sculpting, part of mesh is auto mirroring

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I'm trying to sculpt side of a mountain but when I try to do it the middle part of mesh is mirroring.
[image]

(I draw the left part).

I check normals they are fine [image]
and I didn't use any modifiers apart from multiresolution.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28303/mirror-modifier-applied-but-still-mirroring